# Hexadecimal validation in PLSQL

Tags: regex, validation, plsql, hex

I need to validate a hexadecimal string value (containing only A-F or a-f or 0-9 and combination of this pattern).
I have searched varioud forums and SO as well, and find some solution but none of them is satisfying, at some point some of them are failing to give appropriate results.
Below are some samples.

```
translate(upper(<VALUE-TO-CHECK>), '0123456789ABCDEF', '.') != '..'
```

above code is giving incorrect result for values '1234567890ABCDEF' or '000000' or '100000' etc.

```
REGEXP_LIKE(LTRIM(RTRIM(<VALUE-TO-CHECK>)), '[a-f|A-F|0-9].*');
```

above code is giving incorrect result for values 'Q1W'

```
hex_num := TO_NUMBER(<VALUE-TO-CHECK>, 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN value_error THEN -- When value_error that means not convertible to HEX value
   RETURN FALSE;
```

above code is giving incorrect result for a 64 byte long hexadecimal character value i.e. 'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC'

Can anyone please help on me to validate hexadecimal values.

Comment: `^[a-fA-F0-9]*$` in the `regexp_like` pattern might work.

Comment: I have a done a lot of testing on the code u mentioned, as of now i m satisfied lets see how QA will find it. Thanks man.

Answer (score -2):

```sql
select  
  case
    when regexp_like(:str, '^[^g-zG-Z]*$') then 'Hex'
       else 'NotHex'
  end typ
  from dual
```